# Jenkins 1.452 not promoting builds due to archiving/fingerprinting error

Tags: hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins, jenkins-plugins

I am setting up Jenkins 1.452 with the Promote Build plugin to promote builds. I have a very simple 2 step Promotion path right now.

1. Compile and Install (creates Jar)
2. UAT Deploy (Pushes Jar to my application server)

I have this broken into 2 jobs, and both run successfully on their own - however when I try to setup the promotion process I the following error:

```
Legacy code started this job.  No cause information is available
Building in workspace /Users/theatre/.jenkins/jobs/ActiveCQ API (Compile)/workspace
Promoting ActiveCQ API (Compile) #38
    scheduling build for ActiveCQ API (UAT Deploy)
Recording fingerprints
ERROR: Build artifacts are supposed to be fingerprinted, but build artifact archiving is not configured[8mha:AAAAWB+LCAAAAAAAAABb85aBtbiIQSmjNKU4P08vOT+vOD8nVc8DzHWtSE4tKMnMz/PLL0ldFVf2c+b/lb5MDAwVRQxSaBqcITRIIQMEMIIUFgAAckCEiWAAAAA=[0mbuild hudson.tasks.Fingerprinter@217aa061 FAILURE
Archiving artifacts
build hudson.tasks.ArtifactArchiver@79b75172 FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am attached screen caps of the config for the (Compile) job.

I have Fingerprinting and Archiving setup, and I can even see the list of artifacts w their fingerprints listed in the console.

[Compile build screenshot](https://img.skitch.com/20120302-g7khuum6m6j9ycucdq2b27t795.png)

[UAT Build Showing Archived Artifact w fingerprint](https://img.skitch.com/20120302-kphkm1rk3fbb3ni68mxjusbuwb.png)

[UAT Build Job Config](https://img.skitch.com/20120302-wp9j2e7ptjt44ddf39fpm38im.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some recommendations I would suggest:

1. Do NOT archive and fingerprint in a promotion process.  A promotion process is really a separate job and a separate build.  Instead, you should archive and fingerprint the files in the Compile job's Post-build Actions.  The compile job has to be the origin of the fingerprint for the promotion process to work robustly.
2. In the Deploy job, somehow get the same file that was fingerprinted in the Compile job and also fingerprint it in the Deploy job.
3. I can't see how the Deploy job is getting the jar file.  I would recommend using the Copy Artifact plugin that uses parameters - specifically a build number or perhaps the upstream-build - to retrieve the same file.

Comment: Ah - I was under the impression the contents of the "Promotion" section under Compile occurred during the Compile job, rather than during a separate "Promotion" job. I'll try moving archiving and finger printing to the actual "Jobs" and have the "Promotion" merely copy the artifact from one job to the next. Will let you know what I find. Thanks!!